# CakePHP: Undefined variable, but it is defined

Tags: php

I am using CakePHP 2.4.4. In the Controller I am setting an array :

```
$bla = array();
$bla[] = 'phone';
$bla[] = 'id';
$this->set(compact('bla'));
```

In the view when I try to debug this `$bla` array it debugs well. But when I  try to check if one string is in this array it gives me the `Undefined variable: bla` error. The whole view's code:

```
     array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$val, $key) {
        if (is_numeric($val) AND in_array($key, $bla)) { //this line gives me error: Undefined variable $bla, but it is actually defined
            if (ctype_digit($val)) {
                $val= (int) $val;
            } else {
                $val = (float) $val;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Anonymous function has no access to `$bla`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous function you've created in `array_walk_recursive` has no access to `$bla` and any other outer variables. You should **explicitly** pass this variable to this function with `use`:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$val, $key) use ($bla) {
    if (is_numeric($val) AND in_array($key, $bla)) {
        if (ctype_digit($val)) {
            $val= (int) $val;
        } else {
            $val = (float) $val;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for very fast answer. You are very right!